# Laravel Send URL parameter as hidden input

Tags: php, laravel

I'm confused or been to much in the sun, I have the following situation
when **editing a product**

```
http://app.dev/shops/1/products/2/edit
```

> I added the /shops/1 in the URL because I need to know for what Shop I'm editing the Product.

Now in the Controller I need to know what Shop and Product we're talking about here.
I'm using the following hidden input field to send the product_id to the update Controller

```
<input type="hidden" name="product" value="{{ $product->id }}">
```

**But how do I get the shop_id to the Update Controller.** What's the best way to go about this?

Thank you!

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="shop" value="{{ $shop->id }}"> and get product and shop values in controller

Comment: @BilalAhmed the $shop variable isn't available in this view. It's an edit product view.

Answer (score 2):

route file

```
Route::get('/shops/{shopid}/products/{productid}' , 'testController@gettest');
```

In controller

```
Input::get('shops');
Input::get('products');
```

and also check this

```
Route::get('/', function(){

    echo Input::get('shops');
    echo Input::get('products');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

laravel way

```
 {{ Request::segment(3) }}
```

will give you the id and you can pass it either in hidden input or as you want

PHP way

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

$shop = explode('/', $actual_link);
$shop_id = $shop[1/2/3 or 4];
```

//depending in which position the shop id is coming, you can check it by printing `$shop`

Comment: I have a feeling that when using the Request::segment'ish things that my data is wrong or my url isn't being built correctly. doesn't seem best practice, don't know why

Comment: ok so you need anything else because you dont like this? i have other options too.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a route similar to this

```
Route::post('/shops/{shop_id}/products/{product_id}/edit' , 'TestController@edit');
```

And in your controller you can simply use. Now you have both ids and can do what you want.

```
public function edit($shop_id, $product_id) {
    //do what you want
}
```